# How to decrypt/decompile old toolbox tbx-file in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

I have inherited an arcgis 10 toolbox tbx file for a web application. Are there any way to open the fil in for example Model Builder to see its interiors?

Answer (score 2):

If you have ArcGIS Desktop 10 or greater you should be able to view its contents using ArcCatalog.